# Bootstrap Grid System not working in Angular Components communicating from parent to child

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

app.component.html code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="ads">
        <div class="col-xs-4">
        <app-card  *ngFor="let car of cars"
        [carNotifyBadge]="car.carNotifyBadge"
        [carNotifyYear]="car.carNotifyYear"
        [carCondition]="car.carCondition"
        [carPrice]="car.carPrice"
        [carUsageinKM]="car.carUsageinKM"
        [carName]="car.carName"
        [imgSource]="car.imgSource"
        >
        </app-card>

    </div>
    </div> 
    </div>
```

app.component.ts code

```
                             import { Component ,Input} from '@angular/core';

                         @Component({
                          selector: 'app-root',
                          templateUrl: './app.component.html',
                          styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']      
                         })
                            export class AppComponent {

                            title:string = "Angular-App"

                            cars = [

                                {....},{....},{....}

                    ]


                    }
```

card.component.html

```
                     <div class="card rounded">
                          <div class="card-image">
                              <span class="card-notify-badge">{{carNotifyBadge}}</span>
                              <span class="card-notify-year">{{carNotifyYear}}</span>
                              <img class="img-fluid" [src]="imgSource" alt="Alternate Text" />
                          </div>
                          <div class="card-image-overlay m-auto">
                              <span class="card-detail-badge">{{carCondition}}</span>
                              <span class="card-detail-badge">{{carPrice}}</span>
                              <span class="card-detail-badge">{{carUsageinKM}}</span>
                          </div>
                          <div class="card-body text-center">
                              <div class="ad-title m-auto">
                                  <h5>{{carName}}</h5>
                              </div>
                              <a class="ad-btn" href="#">View</a>
                          </div>
                      </div>
```

card.component.ts

```
                import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

                @Component({
                  selector: 'app-card',
                  templateUrl: './card.component.html',
                  styleUrls: ['./card.component.css']
                })
                export class CardComponent implements OnInit {

                  constructor() { }

                  @Input()  carNotifyBadge = '';
                  @Input()  carUsageinKM = '';
                  @Input()  carName = '';
                  @Input()  carNoticarNotifyYearfyBadge = '';
                  @Input()  imgSource = '';
                  @Input()  carCondition = '';
                  @Input()  carPrice = '';
                  @Input()  carNotifyYear = '';

                  ngOnInit(): void {
                  }

                }
```

Since in app.component.html I have used grid system of bootstrap and using structural directives ngFor I am dynamically adding elements to DOM. I expect the cols to be side by side, whereas I am getting it below each other as shown in the image.

[image]

How to display cols side by side as per bootstrap behaviour ?

Comment: `*ngFor="let car of cars"` is inside element with `col-xs-4`, so you probably want your `car` to have `col-xs-4` class, not parent element

Comment: @MrT Since *ngFor directive is dynamically going to add card.component.html content using selecor <app-card>.
Hence i expect the whole selector to get the bootstrap class col-xs-4 hence <app-card> selector is inside above div with class "col-xs-4".
Can you please elaborate what is your thought process?

Comment: you have 1 div which is `col-xs-4`, containing multiple cars. So the element containing all cars can't be greature than 1/3 of the screen. What you really want to do is that each car has the class `col-xs-4`. So just put the class on the `app-card` tag instead of the parent `div`. You can look at Chrome's debugger and see the size of the boxes, you may better see what we mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure bootstrap CSS is loaded in the application if not, follow these steps.
[Steps to include Bootstrap in Application](https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-bootstrap/)

Pass only car item to the child component, all properties within car object yu will be able to access in the child component.

```js
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" id="ads">
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4" *ngFor="let car of cars">
          <app-card [car]="car"></app-card>
      </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

In the child component, receive the car object inputs from the parent component. 
@Input car;

Comment: Just passing [car] object is a good suggestion.
In card component template, then I need to reference each key individually i.e for example {{car.carName}}. Is this correct ?

Answer (score 0):

make sure, that bootstrap is included in your bundled.css file.

has '#ads' any styles which override bootstraps behavior?

helpful link for install bootstrap [using-bootstrap-with-angular](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/using-bootstrap-with-angular-c83c3cee3f4a)

Comment: the id #ads is been keep for future reference of the div and is having no connection with bootstrap library. I can even remove the id. How do you think the #ads id is over-riding the default bootstrap behaviour ?

Comment: have to define some style properties in your global css or component css which refer on it? If you inspect the #ads element, is there any styles definition from bootstrap?

Comment: typical .row looks like ```
.row {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}```

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem. I use a bootstrap and a commercial theme built on it. I tried to present list of records in bootstrap grid.

I have main app-component which presents the web page. Then I have card-list component which presents grid list within app-component.

When I typed:

```
  styleUrls: [
'./credential-card.component.css',
'../../assets/css/bootstrap.min.css',
'../../assets/css/style.css']
```

Cards were properly styled, but grid didn't work.
When I removed styles

```
  styleUrls: [
'./credential-card.component.css']
```

I lost styling but grid worked fine.

What fixed the problem was to implement another component card-detail and invoke it from card-list. I removed bootstrap CSS from card-list, and added to card-detail.

Finally, I have something like this in card-list component:

```
<section class="pricing-wrapper pt-70 pb-100">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div *ngFor="let item of credentials" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-8">
            <card-detail [shortName]="item.payload.doc.data().shortName" [priceDescription]="item.payload.doc.data().priceDescription"></card-detail>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And this in card-detail:

```
<div class="pricing-style-5 mt-30">
    <div class="pricing-header">
        <div class="pricing d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap">
            <h3 class="heading-3 font-weight-400 title">{{shortName}}</h3>
            <span class="price">{{priceDescription}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```